# Identifying Missing Date Ranges in MS Access

Tags: date, ms-access, date-range

I have a table that is for utility bills. Simplified, each line has an identifier for the property the bill refers to, has a from date and a to date defining the period covered by the bill and a bill amount. Sometimes the bill amount is null. My problem is that there are some periods which are not covered by a line with a bill amount. That is if I group the table by property number and date ranges ascending by from date using only lines which have a non-null bill amount then I get a nice table with no duplicated periods, however there are (a few) gaps.

Now, sometimes the gap is covered exactly or partially by a from to date row in the original data that has a null bill amount. These are legitimate rows and the data is structured in such a way that where this is the case then an adjacent row with a bill amount will include the charge for the period that has a null bill amount. So, I need a table that accounts for all days that are covered in the data without duplication. However, there will sometimes be a real gap in the data, that is a period that is not covered at all and I need to identify those real gaps too.

Here's what seems to me a possible approach.

Step One: First create a table using a grouping query which consolidates all lines with a bill amount by the from to date. I have this.

SELECT Bill_Summary.[Property No], Bill_Summary.[Bill Account No], Bill_Summary.[Bill Date], Bill_Summary.[Property Address], Bill_Summary.[Bill From Date], Bill_Summary.[Bill To Date], [Bill_Summary]![Bill To Date]-[Bill_Summary]![Bill From Date] AS [Days USe], Bill_Summary.Consumption, Bill_Summary.[Total Milk Charge], Bill_Summary.[Total Honey Charge], Bill_Summary.[Total Milk Standing Charge], Bill_Summary.[Total Honey Standing Charge], Bill_Summary.[Bill Amount]
FROM Bill_Summary
GROUP BY Bill_Summary.[Property No], Bill_Summary.[Bill Account No], Bill_Summary.[Bill Date], Bill_Summary.[Property Address], Bill_Summary.[Bill From Date], Bill_Summary.[Bill To Date], [Bill_Summary]![Bill To Date]-[Bill_Summary]![Bill From Date], Bill_Summary.Consumption, Bill_Summary.[Total Milk Charge], Bill_Summary.[Total Honey Charge], Bill_Summary.[Total Milk Standing Charge], Bill_Summary.[Total Honey Standing Charge], Bill_Summary.[Bill Amount]
HAVING (((Bill_Summary.[Bill Amount]) Is Not Null))
ORDER BY Bill_Summary.[Property No], Bill_Summary.[Bill From Date];

Step Two: Then identify from the created table for each property where there are gaps (So result would be a list, Property No, Start date of Gap, End Date of Gap). How do I do that?

Step Three: Then go back to the original data and look for lines (or possibly more than a single line) that exactly fills that gap (or partially fill its, trickier, but never overfills - there can be no overlaps). If I knew how to do Step Two I think I have some clue how to do this step - at least for exact matches for the gaps.

Step Four: Union query the results of steps one and three to create the table that accounts for all days that are covered in the data without duplication.

Step Five: Like step two, identify the real gaps in the final table. Get a list of them by Property No and From Date - To date.

The above uses Access which is the tool I have available to me in the work environment I have to do this.

That's it.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a method to identify missing values - including dates (in the download):

[Find and Generate Missing Values in an Access Table](http://www.devx.com/dbzone/Article/40345)

Comment: Thanks for responding Gustav. I switched to using Excel Power query as my org stopped using Access. Eventually I found a way to do this.

Comment: Four years later!